# How do I add an updated ghostscript to AWS EC2 Instance with Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, ghostscript

How can I get 9.20 - the current version?

(I'm doing the research and will answer as I finish.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is an update to the now stale answer [here](http://www.serveridol.com/2015/07/30/how-do-i-upgrade-the-ghostscript-to-the-latest-in-amazon-ec2/), with a few extra details and a reference to the current repo location.

This may be obvious to the more experienced, but this is intended to help those less experienced with CLI/make/gcc who just need gs.

First set up gcc-c++ if you haven't already [Are all packages necessary? Last two seem to be not needed.]:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ compat-gcc-32 compat-gcc-32-c++
```

Then download, make and install ghostscript:

```
wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs920/ghostscript-9.20.tar.gz
tar -zxvf ghostscript-9.20.tar.gz
cd ghostscript-9.20 
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-dynamic --disable-compile-inits --with-system-libtiff
make
make so
sudo make install
sudo chmod go+w /usr/include/ghostscript/
sudo make soinstall && install -v -m644 base/*.h /usr/include/ghostscript && sudo ln -v -s ghostscript /usr/include/ps
sudo ln -sfv ../ghostscript/9.20/doc /usr/share/doc/ghostscript-9.20
cd ..
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/gs-fonts/files/latest/download?source=files --output-document=ghostscript-fonts-std-8.11.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf ghostscript-fonts-std-8.11.tar.gz -C /usr/share/ghostscript
fc-cache -v /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts/
sudo mkdir /usr/include/ghostscript/
sudo chmod go-w /usr/include/ghostscript/
ghostscript -v
gs -v
```

Comment: To install Ghostscript 9.21, just replace 9.20 with 9.21 and 920 with 921 everywhere in these commands.

Comment: Not sure how this can work, we are chmoding a dir and creating it a little later. Natually I get a cannot find "/usr/include/ghostscript/" during the 1st chmod.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Just update: sudo ln -v -s ghostscript /usr/include/ps with sudo ln -v -s ghostscript /usr/include/gs

Answer (score 0):

You could put the source code on the instance and compile it.....

Comment: Agreed!  Figured I'd get the answer up before sleep, but didn't happen that way.  Step by step answer provided now.

Answer (score 0):

Met an error when ran

```
sudo chmod go+w /usr/include/ghostscript/
```

because the folder didn't exist yet.

So I did minor adjustment to the command order:

```
 wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs920/ghostscript-9.20.tar.gz
tar -zxvf ghostscript-9.20.tar.gz
cd ghostscript-9.20 
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-dynamic --disable-compile-inits --with-system-libtiff
make
make so
sudo make install
sudo mkdir /usr/include/ghostscript/
sudo chmod go+w /usr/include/ghostscript/
sudo make soinstall && install -v -m644 base/*.h /usr/include/ghostscript && sudo ln -v -s ghostscript /usr/include/ps
sudo ln -sfv ../ghostscript/9.20/doc /usr/share/doc/ghostscript-9.20
cd ..
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/gs-fonts/files/latest/download?source=files --output-document=ghostscript-fonts-std-8.11.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf ghostscript-fonts-std-8.11.tar.gz -C /usr/share/ghostscript
fc-cache -v /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts/
sudo chmod go-w /usr/include/ghostscript/
ghostscript -v
gs -v
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used below link and followed the steps for linux AMI
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/ghostscript-9.25-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html
you can check with gs -v and ghostscript -v